# Split elements in array and add line break, then join - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, join, split

I'm mapping through data in Reactjs. This JSX:

```
{place.venue.location.formattedAddress}
```

Is mapping through this Axios data request, specially, this array in my response:

```
formattedAddress: Array(5)
0 : "Chester Rd"
1 : "London"
2 : "Greater London"
3 : "NW1 4NR"
4 : "United Kingdom"
```

As a result, when I'm mapping, it returns the data, in one sentence, all joined together.  Exactly like this:

```
Serpentine RdHyde ParkGreater LondonW2 2TP
```

I'm trying to map through, split and join with a line break, but it's not working.  My address stops appearing completely.  What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code, (I've sliced, so I can remove the country off the end of the address).

```
{place.venue.location.formattedAddress.slice(0,4).split(',').join('<br />')}
```

Comment: Only strings have a `.split` method. If `formattedAddress` is an array, then `formattedAddress.slice(...)` returns another array. Just drop the `.split`.

Comment: perfect, thank you @FelixKling!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    var arr = ["hello", "there", "world"]
    return(
      <div>
        {arr.map(s=><React.Fragment>{s}<br/></React.Fragment>)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

1 You are calling `split` on array, but it is a string method.

2 You cant use join using `'<br />'`. `jsx` will treat it as string.

you should map over your array elements and return an array of jsx.

```
{place.venue.location.formattedAddress.slice(0,4).map(s=><React.Fragment>s <br/></React.Fragment>)}
```

Comment: This is not quite like `join` as `join` would not append a `<br />` to the end of the array of elements

Comment: @Trevor Here is how to do it without final `<br />` https://stackoverflow.com/a/68680034/4840661

Answer (score 3):

Using map without generating an ending break.

```
const breakedAttributes = attributes.map((attribute, index) => {
    const isLast = attributes.length === (index + 1);
    return !isLast ? <>{attribute}<br/></> : attribute;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50709358/5625547)'s method will leave a trailing `<br />`, I'd share my approach.

---

Use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce,) on your array to insert a `<br />` between each item, since React can render Array's without any issues, this will result in the expected behaviour:

```
{arr.reduce((p, c) => [ p, <br />, c ])}
```

```html
<div>
    hello
    <br>
    there
    <br>
    world
</div>
```

---

##### React 17 Demo

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const arr = [ "hello", "there", "world" ];

    return (
        <div>
            {arr.reduce((p, c) => [ p, <br />, c ])}
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```